# Различное оформление описания действий в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

На текущий момент не согласован внешний вид сообщений с описанием действий в очереди проверок. Несколько скриншотов по этому случаю:

[image: низкое качество]

[image: первый вопрос]

[image: первый ответ]

[image: закрытие]

[image: правки]

[image: повторное открытие]

[image: запоздалые ответы]

- Где-то пояснения действий указаны в скобках, где-то нет.
- Где-то есть лишние пробелы перед запятыми, где-то нет.
- Где-то есть точки в конце предложений, где-то нет.

Возможно, в других типах очередей также имеются схожие проблемы.

Для упрощения решения проблемы стоит ещё обратить внимание на feature-request на MSE: [Move whitespace to the localizable string for review option's description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306170/339911)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На текущий момент дизайн обработки элементов в очередях проверок существенно изменился и стал более унифицированным. Действия вынесены в отдельный блок справа и имеют чётко выраженные заголовки и описания. Обозначенной проблемы более не наблюдается. Ниже несколько примеров:

> [image: предлагаемые правки]

> [image: голоса за переоткрытие]

> [image: сообщения низкого качества]