# В тексте всплывающей подсказки вопроса появляется пустое место, если вопрос содержит картинки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Содержимое всплывающей подсказки [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3757/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) содержит много пробельных строк там где в самом вопросе расположены картинки (возможно и другие элементы трансформируются в пустые строки хинта).

[image: пустые строки]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за сообщение. Мы теперь убираем лишние пустые строки из подсказки.

Comment: Что-то [сломалось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iwq7.png) или в чём может быть дело?